# How do I access the Pi's GPIO using Google's Project Brillo/Android Things?

Tags: gpio, pi-3, android, android-things

An [arstechnica.com article published today](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2016/12/google-brillo-rebrands-as-android-things-googles-internet-of-things-os/) outlined Google's latest progress towards their IoT platform, Android Things (formerly Project Brillo). [It looks like it supports the Pi 3](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html).

Is it possible to access the Pi's GPIO pins from a native Android application? Can you provide a brief example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the GPIO pins using the [new Peripheral I/O API](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/gpio.html).

Example for turning `BCM6` pin to `HIGH`:

```
PeripheralManagerService pioService = new PeripheralManagerService();
Gpio pin = pioService.openGpio("BCM6");
gpio.setDirection(Gpio.DIRECTION_OUT_INITIALLY_LOW);
// turn on.
gpio.setValue(true);
// turn off.
gpio.setValue(false);
```

Make sure to check the pinout for the Raspberry Pi 3 on the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi-io.html) or on [pinout.xyz](https://pinout.xyz/)